# Sharing ArcGIS Pro project with custom tool(s) and maps

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have an ArcGIS Pro project with a map and a custom ModelBuilder tool that converts selected GIS features in the map to a CAD file.  The layers in the map come from an enterprise geodatabase and a network file folder accessible to everyone.  The tool is also in the same network file folder. I added the tool to the "Analysis" tab.  The intent is to share the project with others so they can use the tool. Everything works fine on my computer, however, I've emailed the .aprx file and .ppkx to a colleague and while the files open up correctly, when he clicks on the tool in the analysis tab, he gets a "tool has failed to open" error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using unc paths? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/project-package.htm

Comment: Hi Mapperz, thank you for the reply.  Yes, I'm using UNC paths.

Comment: It might be that adding the tool to the analysis tab is a customisation to ArcPro under _your profile setting_ on your machine, which obviously is not their machine.... That's my guess.

Comment: Hornbydd, I think you're onto something.  I will have to wait to test on colleague's computer.  Will follow-up soon, thank you!

Comment: The only way I was able to get this to work is by exporting/importing ribbon customization using the .proExportedUI file.  This is odd because every time a user imports ribbon customization, it completely overwrites their existing ribbon configuration (doesn't just add to the existing ribbon configuration).  Furthermore, rather than just sharing a .aprx or package, one has to share the customization file and expect the end user to know how to import it.  I'm sure there is something I'm missing but I've got a working solution for now.  Thank you for all the help/input!